# How can I make my Android application to act as a Beacon?

Tags: android, beacon

I want to develop two Android applications out of which one application should act as a Beacon. That is, one of my application installed in one device should listen certain events from the other app installed in other device and should broadcast some information on listening those events.
I read many articles and I found that the Android device must have Bluetooth LE hardware and it must have peripheral mode enabled by the device manufacturer. But most of the manufacturer as well as Google itself has disabled peripheral mode.

So my question is there a way (a Beacon library available?), so that I can make my application to act as Beacon.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To integrate beacon in your app use this https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) to make a device both transmit as a beacon and detect/decode beacon transmissions.

It is true that devices must have BLE hardware for this to work, Android 4.3+ to detect beacons and Android 5.x+ to transmit as beacons.  While not all devices with 5.x+ support peripheral mode needed to transmit, most popular devices do.  Google has **not** disabled this, and their newer Nexus and Pixel devices support transmission as well.

The library linked above has a *[list of devices](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html)* known to support transmission, and includes [example code](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html) showing how to determine this at runtime on a specific device.

If a device does not support peripheral mode, there is nothing you can do short of rooting the device and trying to write a new Bluetooth driver yourself.